# On Demand Resources Initial Install Tags do not work as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8

My understanding of On Demand Resources Initial Install Tags (ON_DEMAND_RESOURCES_INITIAL_INSTALL_TAGS) Is that these will be downloaded on installation.

as outlined in

WWDC15 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/214/

and

[Apple Documentation on Pre Fetch Tags](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/Tagging.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH3-SW1)

> The default category for a tag is Download Only On Demand. The view
>   displays the tags grouped by their prefetch category and the total
>   size for each category. The size is based on the device that was the
>   target of the last build. Tags can be dragged between categories.
>
> **Initial install tags**. The resources are downloaded **at the same time as
>   the app**. The size of the resources is included in the total size for
>   the app in the App Store. The tags can be purged when they are not
>   being accessed by at least one NSBundleResourceRequest object.
>
> **Prefetch tag order**. The resources start downloading after the app is
>   installed. The tags will be downloaded in the order in which they are
>   listed in the Prefetched tag order group. Dowloaded only on demand.
>   The tags are downloaded when requested by the app.

However my experience is that the assets are not downloaded on install. This can be seen in the disk section of debug navigator in XCode 8 (suggested in [Apple Documentation on How to use debugger/disk](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/DebugTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH6-SW2))

[image]

According to WWDC above this should simply work in the Simulator as if in live.

A similar question can be seen [Initial Install Tags usage and verification during Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134879) however this is not a duplicate because my contention is that this functionality does not work at all as expected.

This thread on Apple forums also contends this does not function 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9530 but with out any definitive answer.

Has anyone managed to get On Demand Resources Initial Install Tags  to work as expected or is my understanding of what this feature is supposed to do wrong ?

Comment: I got Initial Install Tags to work properly. As you have mentioned, it doesn't work while debugging the app. It can be tested only via TestFlight or only in live. In both these cases, the resources are downloaded as part of the app and can be just accessed. But while debugging, we will have to use beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler or conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler to download and access the resources. It will not be a real-time scenario.

Comment: @Andrew , do you feel that this is a bug, or that it is the expected result ?

Comment: Definitely a bug (doesn't work as documented). But, this looks like the only way to make it work.

Comment: Did you get a chance to test this in live? I mean, on the Store version?

Comment: @andrew No we are still supporting ios 8 , so cannot try yet

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. I am running into issues while testing my Store build (using Promotional code) on iPhones running 10.1.1.

Comment: Adding the resources into pre-fetch tags worked for me in the simulator.

Comment: It's didn't work even on testflight for me.